# How can I bulk move files from one folder to another based on filenames?

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line, scripting

So I currently have a folder e.g. C/Users/MyDocs/Datasets with over 200,000 XML datasets in it and I need to extract 500 specific ones based on the name into a new folder e.g. C/Users/MyDocs/Curated. For example, the file names are:

```
TCD989890123
TCD123090909
TCD981203892
```

I have the specific file names in excel that was given to me. What would be the best way to extract all these files? I'm assuming that I can use some bash or powershell scripting but unfortunately this is new territory for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry i meant batch I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sublime to do it. 
Copy all lines from the excel to sublime, click Ctrl + A and then Ctrl + Shift + L.
Now you can write command to move every file, something like -

`mv C/Users/MyDocs/Datasets/TCD989890123 C/Users/MyDocs/Curated`

`mv C/Users/MyDocs/Datasets/TCD123090909 C/Users/MyDocs/Curated`

`mv C/Users/MyDocs/Datasets/TCD981203892 C/Users/MyDocs/Curated`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. Much appreciated :)